# Converted ArrayList of custom objects to JSON using gson library, ClassCastException when retrieving back those custom objects

Tags: android, json, gson, classcastexception

I have used the Google's GSON library to convert an `ArrayList` of my custom objects to JSON in order to store it into `SharedPreferences`. The class of the objects stored in the ArrayList is like this:

```
class CustomObject {
  String name;
  Map<String, Long>  topGrades;
  Map<String, Long> lowestGrades;

  CustomObject(String name, Map<String, Long>  topGrades, Map<String, Long>  lowestGrades) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lowestGrades = lowestGrades;
    this.topGrades = topGrades;
  }
}
```

I saved an `ArrayList` of objects of `CustomObject` to `SharedPreferences` like:

```
List<CustomObject> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
//Populate the list with objects of type CustomObject
...
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                    "tests.dataSharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String dataListJson = gson.toJson(dataList);
editor.putString("tests.dataListJsonKey", dataListJson);
editor.commit();
```

The I retrieved the `List` from the JSON like:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("tests.dataSharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String dataJson = sharedPreferences.getString("tests.dataListJsonKey", "");

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            final List<CustomObject> dataList = gson.fromJson(dataJson, ArrayList.class);
```

**SO far so good. But now in order to get the `name`s of all `CustomObject`s in `dataList` above into a String array, in the following loop, I tried to retrieve a `CustomObject` from the `dataList`, *But I got `ClassCastException`***:

```
        String[] namesArray = new String[dataList.size()];

        for (int x=0; x<namesArray.length; x++) {
            CustomObject customObject = dataList.get(x);//********ClassCastException********************************
            namesArray[x] = customObject.name;
        }
```

**I got**

```
06-18 12:28:11.689: E/AndroidRuntime(1536): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to tests.CustomObject
```

The question is why and what is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gson must know the type of Object to convert to. That is, in order to serialize it must know the exact type. When you pass the type as ArrayList.class it doesn't provide Gson with complete necessary informations about your Object.

One thing you can do is create a wrapper class which contains your ArrayList. Then provide that class to Gson as your second parameter.

```java
class Wrapper {

    ArrayList<CustomObject> dataList; 
    //constrctor 
    public Wrapper() {
       //empty constructor for Gson
    }
    //setter for dataList
    public void setDataList(ArrayList<CustomObject> dataList){
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

}
```

Try this for serializing and deserializing:

```java
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
//populate list
wrapper.setDataList(list);

//serialize
String dataListJson = gson.toJson(wrapper);

//deserialize
Gson gson = new Gson();
Wrapper dataWrapper = gson.fromJson(dataListJson, Wrapper.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace

```
 final List<CustomObject> dataList = gson.fromJson(dataJson, ArrayList.class);
```

to

```
final List<CustomObject> dataList = gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<List<CustomObject>>() {
          }.getType());
```

Comment: I get `The constructor TypeToken<List<CustomObject>>() is not visible` at `new TypeToken<List<CustomObject>>()` :s